# Question about norms of a matrix when exchanging two of its rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Assume I exchange two rows of a square complex $n\times n $ matrix.

Are the Euclidean norm and the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of the new matrix (obtained from the first one by exchanging two of its rows) the same as the orginal one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by the Euclidean norm you mean the operator norm induced by the Euclidean norm on vectors,
$$\lVert A\rVert_2 = \max_{x\ne 0} \frac{\lVert Ax\rVert_2}{\lVert x\rVert_2},$$
then this follows easily from the facts that permuting the rows of $A$ is the same as premultiplying it by an appropriate permutation matrix $P$, and that $\lVert Py \rVert_2 = \lVert y\rVert_2$ for any vector $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Hilber-Schmidt norm is defined by

$$\|A\|_{HS}^2:=\sum_{i,j}|A_{i,j}|^2$$

Check the [wikipedia page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator).   Hence we see that this sum is independent of interchange the rows or column.   Also Euclidean norm sees $A$ as point in $C^n$ and hence norm is independent if we exchange the rows.

Answer (score 1):

These are both entrywise norms, and so...

Comment: I thought (and Wikipedia agrees) that the Euclidean norm of a matrix was the operator norm $\lVert A \rVert_2 = \max_{x\ne0}\lVert Ax\rVert_2/\lVert x\rVert_2$, and that's not an entrywise norm. If Wikipedia is incorrect, someone should correct it. If the term is ambiguous, the asker should clarify which meaning is intended.

Comment: I guess it is ambiguous! I was using [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html)